# How to use multiple themes for multiple matplotlib imports

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I am importing multiple matplotlib as names within my python program and would like to use different styles for different plots.
However when i change the style for one plot (say : dark_background) it changes the style for all other plots as well.

suggestions shall be appreciated

Current import is something like this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt_surfacegt 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt_mascon 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt_gravmod 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt_realtime 
plt_realtime.style.use('dark_background')
```

it should only change the theme for  plt_realtime to dark however all others are changed to dark as well.!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot exactly explain *why* this wouldn't work, but it seems to me a crazy idea to achieve your desired result.

Instead, I think you should use [matplotlib's context manager](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#temporary-styling) to change the style sheet on a per-plot basis. Something like (from the link):

```
with plt.style.context('dark_background'):
    plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)), 'r-o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why this doesn't work is basic python: Even if you import a module several times it stays the same module.